# pass variable from php to html / js

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

So I have a JavaScript that returns an output variable looking like this:

```
<script id="cat-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="chart">
        <h2>{{Name}}</h2>
        <h3 style="color:#ff0099;font-size:250%"> {{Status}}</h3>

</script>
```

What I would like to do is have it as a part of this php snippet:

```
<?php
    $status = {{Status}};
    if ($status = "1") {
        echo "Good day, bud!";}
    else {
        echo "Good night, pal!";}
?>
```

the `{{Status}}` doesn't work in the php snippet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Irrelevant, but `if ($status = "1")` should be `if ($status == "1")` with two `=` signs. Assignment vs comparison.

Comment: How should that work? Where is the value coming from?

Comment: Where in that code are you passing a variable from php to html / js ??

Comment: I. 
<?php
    $status == {{Status}};
    if ($status = "1") {
        echo "Good day, bud!";}
    else {
        echo "Good night, pal!";}
?>

II.
The value comes from a DB  via JS. This <h2>{{Name}}</h2> produces an output

III. 
With a JS

Comment: And how does "a JS" transfer that value back to to server where PHP could evaluate it?

Answer (score 0):

You Must On Parse HTML AND JavaScript AS PHP String

Simple Example :

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
....
....
....
</head>
<body>
<p>Your Username Is :{{username}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php 
$username ="Test";
$content=file_get_contents("/theme/index.html");
$content=str_replace("{{username}}",$username,$content);

echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mostafa,
How does this line work: $content=file_get_contents("/theme/index.html"); ?